# Помогите разобраться с сокетами (python)

Tags: python, веб-программирование, сеть, сокет, tcp

У меня есть код для сервера:

```
import socket

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sock.bind(('localhost', 25))
sock.listen(5)
sock.setblocking(False)

while True:
    try:
        client, addr = sock.accept()
    except socket.error:
        pass
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        client.close()
    else:
        client.setblocking(True)
        result = client.recv(1024)
        print(f'From adress {addr} came message {result.decode()}')
```

И клиента:

```
import socket

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sock.connect(('localhost', 25))

while True:
    message = input('Send message to our server:\n')
    sock.send(message.encode('utf-8'))
```

Идея заключается в посылке нескольких сообщений клиентом на сервер. Но почему-то в консоли сервера отображается только первое сообщение, которое клиент отправляет при самом подключении. Далее я прошёлся дебагером и выяснил, что цикл просто постоянно заходит в блок except socket.error . Почему так происходит, ведь я же уже подключился с клиента и какая разница в том, сколько сообщений я отправлю? Тогда получается мне каждый раз по новой надо создавать новый клиентский сокет, по новой подключатся и отправлять сообщения? Можно ли вообще так сделать, чтобы через одно подключение отправлялись сразу несколько сообщений по очереди? Если да, то как? 
Заранее спасибо за ответ, надеюсь суть проблемы ясна.

Comment: Переделайте цикл так, чтобы не пытаться снова и снова давать команду `accept` на уже установленное соединение. Например, устанавливая и проверяя флаг. И добавьте `break` после закрытия сокета

Comment: Вам правильно написали. Вы после принятия сообщения на сервере ждёте нового подключения (`sock.accept()`).

Comment: Правильно ли я понимаю, что при таком подходе к серверу сможет подключится только один клиент?

Comment: Да, правильно. Если вам требуется обрабатывать несколько соединений, то при наивном подходе следует сохранять все соединения в массив и затем в дополнительном цикле их опрашивать на предмет новых сообщений. При правильном подходе следует использовать многопоточность и создавать отдельную нить (thread) для каждого соединения, содержащую примерно такой цикл, как Ваш. Используйте @SergeyNudnov при ответе, чтобы я увидел эти ответы.